# How to POST back a textarea with enters?

Tags: php, javascript, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a HTML / Javascript page with some textarea. The user are typing their text with enter to create new lines. The problem lies when the form is submitted via ajax (with the functionnality of jQuery) to PHP. The text is received but without the enter.

How do you pass enters from HTML textarea to PHP?

I'm in POST in this context.

The textarea content the following

> asdf
>
> éè ï
>
> "
>
> '
>
> ``
>
> ||
>
> @£¢¤¬¦²³³

But the PHP receive the following:

> asdféè ï"'``||@£¢¤¬¦²³³

Comment: What is the contents of the textarea when sent over the wire?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the behavior on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Textareas do preserve whitespace.  Can you be more specific or give us an example?

Comment: how do you know the enter is not sent ? are you viewing the result in a webpage ? (in this case all 'enters' should be replaced by <BR> tag so the browser can render it to new lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably not converting newlines into breaklines:

```
echo nl2br($_POST['myTextArea']);
```

And to make it safe for output:

```
echo nl2br( htmlentities( $_POST['myTextArea'], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8" ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

The `enter keys` are getting saved, but they are preserved as `\n` which will not show up as line breaks in HTML. You need to do an `nl2br()` while displaying the content back in the web page. This will convert the `\n` line break characters to `<br>` and show it correctly in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PHP function I used to fix the issue:

```
rawurldecode(utf8_decode($_POST['myTextArea']))
```